# C# Create a Process with already elevated privileges

Tags: c#, process

I am creating a software that require run as administrator when run, most client already aware of it and running it without problems. However this software require to run another software using Process.Start call it SoftwareB. When running SoftwareB, softwareB also require elevated privileges. How do I run softwareB without asking the client for UAC again, because the softwareB should be running in background and the software might be running it when user is not attending the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call Process.Start from elevated process, then new process will be elevated as well.